# Using classes for view

Tags: java, jsp

If I have a set of HTML building blocks that are used by many different components, can I use a Java class for that ? Currently I use JSP, but it seems a bit difficult.

For eg: **com.mydomain.view.Table.java**

and from a JSP I create an object of it, like this :

```
Table tb = new Table(data);
String html = tb.getHtml();
```

So is this okay ? good ? better ? or best ?

if not, what is the standard way to achieve this ?

PS: The `Table` class here has nothing to do with html `<table>` tag. What that class does is create a tabular structure of data. It may or may not use a html `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there is no standard way.

> So is this okay ? good ? better ? or best ?

The answer depends on the goal of the software you are making.
One important factor to consider is "[eventual efficiency](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2011/02/theres-only-one-valid-metric-for-developer-productivity-and-quality/)".

Looking only at the Table class, it looks good. Constructor clearly states it's dependency on 'data'. getHtml() method, in my opinion, is where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other views (Swing, Android, ...), you end up with having additional `getSwing()` or `getAndroid()` methods. Anyway that's OK, if the `Table` class is a generic intermediate layer between the real model and the view.

Another possibility is to pass the model or the `Table` to the JSP view layer, and let the view layer decide how to transform it to HTML. For example by using a taglib (which eventually may call `getHtml` as well). If you pass the `Table`, the view gets generic somehow as well (because it can't really decide on how the data is rendered).

Answer (score 0):

With html building blocks, one solution is using jQuery load that returns html. 
The combination of Spring MVC with Apache Tiles view is best suited for this.

$("elementId").load("${context}/rest_url_returning_html_building_block");